# One tableView With two different cell.xib ,If i press one cell it need to show second cell. How?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I take tableView and two different cell.xib files , I want to display when i click cell1 then i should display cell2 data.

```
class TableView: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var array1 = ["Click1","Click2"]
    var array2 = [[ "one","two","Three"],["Four","Five"]]
    var selectedArray = [String]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MainCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "MainCell")//This is used to add xib file with identifier

            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SecondCell", bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "SecondCell")

        }

        //MARK:DataSource Methods
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return array1.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell") as! MainCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
        //MARK: tableViewDelegate Method
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondCell") as! SecondCell

            selectedArray = array2[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = selectedArray[indexPath.row]


        }


    }
```

Tell how can i do that if i press first cell it should show 2nd cell values as per indexPath.row

Comment: And what about if the user presses cell2 then?

Comment: And why are you returning 1 in numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Decide whether you need to `change data or cell?` In `didSelectRowAt` you can not `dequeue a cell`. Either change the data or on click reload the `tableview` with a `boolean` check which will `dequeue your second cell`.

Comment: When i click on click2 i need to display four,five on same tableView.

Comment: Your post is too confusing. You want create a tableview with collapsible/expand sections, right? Refer to : https://medium.com/@legonaftik/uitableview-with-collapsible-sections-927d726b985c

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to achieve expandable cells. You can use the header cell for this one.

You might want to read [this](https://medium.com/@evicoli/creating-simple-table-view-header-animated-with-collapse-d36e74452ef0):

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can add a flag which indicates whether the first cell was tapped.

```
var wasFirstCellTapped = false
```

Then `numberOfRowsInSection` depends on this flag:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return wasFirstCellTapped ? array1.count : 1
}
```

In `didSelectRowAt:indexPath` set this flag to `true`. And perform tableView changes. The simplest way is to call `tableView.reloadData()`. But you can animate this using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`

Answer (score 0):

```
var allCellsArray = ["Click1","Click2"]
var displayingCellsArray = ["Click1"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return displayingCellsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell!
        if displayingCellsArray[indexPath.row] == "Click1" {
            cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell") as! MainCell
        }else {
            cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondCell") as! SecondCell
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = displayingCellsArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    //MARK: tableViewDelegate Method
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let data = displayingCellsArray[indexPath.row]
        //Below logic will show (Cell2 if Cell1 is clicked and hide Cell1)
        // (and show Cell1 if clicked Cell2 and hide Cell2)
        if data == "Click1" {
            displayingCellsArray = [allCellsArray.last!]            
        }else {
            displayingCellsArray = [allCellsArray.first!]
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

You should handle such logic in a separate datasource array by adding/removing that sort of data from this array which shows particular cells.
E.g 
In your case you have two values in `array` `Click1` & `Click2`
`Click1` shows `MainCell` & `Click2` shows `SecondCell`
So first add `Click1` in your array and when this cell is tapped simply add `Click2` in your array and `reload`. If you want to remove `MainCell` when `SecondCell` is displaying then while adding `Click2` simply remove `Click1`

Comment: here i have 2 different cell.xib, If i click on click1 ,  one and two should show below click1 array in tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the second cell on click of first cell..

Refer this example to expand and collapse the cells

https://github.com/jonasman/JNExpandableTableView